# SSH from SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssh

to be clear I do not want to ssh sql server, instead I am looking to execute a command from sql server to ssh a device

we have a database that contains a list of PSK from WAP's, we have reached the point where we need to centrally manage them instead of manually change them.

All of the WAPS are SSH compatible but before I start down a rabbit hole I wanted to see if anyone has SSH from SQL Server, if I could do this then I could automate the PSK's changing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SSH is not built-into SQL server.  However SQL Server does have some very strong options, but they are disabled by default.  Do you have permissions to 1) enable system stored procedures or 2)install extended stored procedures or 3) enable CLR procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have built-in support for making outbound SSH connections. However, you can create a [User-Defined Function (UDF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx) using the Common Language Runtime (CLR). This allows you to use the .Net language of your choosing (C#, VB, etc.) to implement custom functionality. You could create a CLR UDF that accepts the appropriate arguments, calls out via SSH then returns one value (a scalar-valued function) or multiple values/rows (a table-valued function) which you then can store in your database.

Keep in mind that .Net currently doesn't have built-in SSH support so you'll have to use a third-party library (there are at least a couple open source options available) or call out to an external application.

Another option would be to put key update requests into a SQL Server's Service Broker queue then use an external (outside of SQL Server) program (like something custom written in .Net) to process requests from that queue.